# Adding White Space in Java

Tags: java

I'm getting the correct numbers outputted but I can't figure out how to get a space in between the numbers. I tried manually adding the space in by using + " " but it just gave me an error. Can someone please explain to me what I'm missing?

1.587.9063.20  <--current output
1.58 7.90 63.20  <--needed output

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class LabProgram {
       
       public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon) {
          double drivingCost = (drivenMiles / milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon;
          return drivingCost;
       } 
       
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
          double milesPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
          double dollarsPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
          System.out.printf("%.2f", drivingCost(10, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
          System.out.printf("%.2f", drivingCost(50, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
          System.out.printf("%.2f\n", drivingCost(400, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code as text. There's no easy way to try code in an image ourselves, we can't copy snippets of it into our answers, and it won't show up in future Google searches. See also: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Comment: What does "it just gave me an error" mean?  What is the error?

Comment: It's "printf", just put a space in it?

Comment: @Dave Newton the question is how do I do that???

Comment: I'm at a loss to understand how you can know how to add a newline after the number (third printf) but not figure out how to add a space after the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can add space after %.2f  --> "%.2f "

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon) {
        return  (drivenMiles /milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Miles/Gallon");
        double milesPerGallon =scnr.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Dollars/Gallon");
        double dollarsPerGallon =scnr.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(10, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
        System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(50, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", drivingCost(100, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon));
    }
}
```

[image]